# Dynamically Creating repeated textbox and textbox groups fails in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

MY code is like this

```
<body>
<div ng-app=''>
    <div ng-controller="questionCtrl">
        <div>
            <ul />
            <li ng-repeat="prdElement in palletElement">
                <input type="text" ng-model="prdElement.name" placeholder="Name" required />
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="elemnt in prdElement.children">

                        <div>
                            <span>
                                <input type="text" ng-model="elemnt.name" placeholder="Name" required />
                            </span>
                            <span ng-hide="elemnt.length == 1">
                                <a href ng-click="prdElement.splice($index, 1)">remove</a>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href ng-click="newPrdItem($event)">New Item</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>


        </div>
        <div>
            <button ng-click="showitems($event)">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div id="displayitems" style="visibility:hidden;">
            {{prdElement}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
    function questionCtrl($scope){
var counter=0;

$scope.palletElement = [{
    name: 'Pallet 1',
    children: [{
        name: '11',
    }, {
        name: '12',
    }]
}, {
    name: 'Pallet 2',
    children: [{
        name: '21'
    }, {
        name: '22'
    }]
}]



$scope.newPrdItem = function ($event) {
    counter++;
    $scope.prdElement.children.push({ id: counter, name: ''});
    $event.preventDefault();
}

$scope.showitems = function($event){
    $('#displayitems').css('visibility','none');
}
```

}

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JDS2U/70/)**
all looks okay to me but adding and removing elements functionality is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `$scope.palletElement` which is an array of two positions each one has and object with `children` property, however in your `$scope.newPrdItem` function you are accessing the `children` element of the array (which not exist) instead of accessing the `children` property of the object in the first or second array position, so this works:

`$scope.prdElement[0].children.push({ id: counter, name: ''});`
`$scope.prdElement[1].children.push({ id: counter, name: ''});`

Instead of:

`$scope.prdElement.children.push({ id: counter, name: ''});`

A possible way to do this is to change `$scope.newPrdItem` function to pass the `prdElement` where new children element is added.

Another problem is in your remove function, in this case you're making a similar mistake, in this case you are applying `splice` in a object instead of an array, so use:

`prdElement.children.splice($index, 1)`

Instead of:

`prdElement.splice($index, 1)`

All together in your code looks like:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JDS2U/75/)

#### js

```
function questionCtrl($scope){
    var counter=0;

    $scope.palletElement = [{
        name: 'Pallet 1',
        children: [{
            name: '11',
        }, {
            name: '12',
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Pallet 2',
        children: [{
            name: '21'
        }, {
            name: '22'
        }]
    }]



    $scope.newPrdItem = function (prdElement, $event) {
        counter++;
        prdElement.children.push({ id: counter, name: '', inline: true });
        $event.preventDefault();
    }

    $scope.showitems = function($event){
        $('#displayitems').css('visibility','none');
    }
}
```

#### HTML

```
<body>
    <div ng-app=''>
        <div ng-controller="questionCtrl">
            <div>
                <ul />
                <li ng-repeat="prdElement in palletElement">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="prdElement.name" placeholder="Name" required />
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="elemnt in prdElement.children">

                            <div>
                                <span>
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="elemnt.name" placeholder="Name" required />
                                </span>
                                <span ng-hide="elemnt.length == 1">
                                    <a href ng-click="prdElement.children.splice($index, 1)">remove</a>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <hr />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href ng-click="newPrdItem(prdElement,$event)">New Item</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button ng-click="showitems($event)">Submit</button>
            </div>
            <div id="displayitems" style="visibility:hidden;">
                {{prdElement}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: It's a similar problem in remove, now you're applying slice on a `prdElement` (which it's not an array) instead of applying to `prdElement.children`, so use: `prdElement.children.splice($index, 1)` instead of `prdElement.splice($index,1)`. I will update my answer.